# why isn't animation working for max-height?

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331169/2545680) we can animate `max-height` property, however for some reason an animation isn't applied to `max-height` property specified like this ([see plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LQOnBwuJX7mMRVVl4oCN?p=preview)):

```
.animated-div {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightblue;
  opacity:1;
  height:500px;
}

.animated-div.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.animated-div.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.animated-div.ng-hide {
  height:0;
  opacity:0;
}
```

Yet if I change max-height to height it works well. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all works fine but your example isn't setup properly to demonstrate the effect. The `animated-div` is just not high enough to see the effect, before max-height kicks in, opacity is already so low you can't see the effect anymore.

See my [updated fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/F6jcbWQcpU6U28bZvRDQ) for a demonstration (I added more text, deleted the opacity change and made the transition in two seconds for demonstration purposes; and the transition works on hover to see the effect multiple times without restarting/reloading).

Comment: I had `overflow:hidden` in place, you must've overlooked it. When I added more text it then became obvious that the solution worked. Thanks)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I indeed didn't notice the line. Still, the `animated-div` wasn't large enough to see the change in max-height before the opacity was too low to see it. Changed my answer regarding the overflow part.